# AFNetwork For Swift

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, nsurlconnection

Am switching to Swift from Objective-C. In Objective-C I used `AFNetworking for Client-Server communication (NSURLConnection)`. I googled and referred some blogs for the network communication and found the following links for reference.

1. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking
2. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

I downloaded the zip file from the GitHub link. But, both are written in Objective-C. Can anyone please help me to use AFNetworking in Swift? 
Looking for your help. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using CocoaPods for dependency management then just add `pod 'Alamofire'` to `Podfile`, `import Alamofire` in Swift source and use it.

Comment: @AshishKakkad You can perfectly use AFNetwork wit a swift bringing header. But Alamofire is swift and therefore preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add AFNetworking to your swift project

In Build Settings -> Defines Module set to Yes

In Build Settings -> Swift compiler -> Objective-C bridging file set the name of bridging file ‘bridge.h’

for example in bridge.h write:

```
#import "AFNetworking.h"
```

see this tutorial for create [`bridging-Header`](https://victorliew.quora.com/AFNetworking-With-Swift-Tutorial)

for additional HTTP Method for how to use `AFNetWork` see this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@aommiez/afnetwork-integrate-swfit-80514b545b40)

Comment: is based of developer preference , how do we force to developer to use , we can suggest correct my friend

Comment: Yes, You are right :)

Answer (score 1):

AFNetworking is written in Objective-C, but you can use it in Swift projects. My only caveat is that it has two parallel implementations offering similar functionality, `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` which is `NSURLConnection` based, and `AFHTTPSessionManager`, which is `NSURLSession` based. The thing is that `NSURLConnection` is now deprecated, so if you use AFNetworking, use `AFHTTPSessionManager`.

Having said all of that, for Swift projects, you really should just go ahead and use Alamofire, which is written by the same author, but is written in Swift, not Objective-C.